# How can I dynamically display browser on 2nd monitor when using watir with Rubymine?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, rubymine

How do I force my browser to come up on the monitor opposite Rubymine in a dual monitor setup?

I am trying to test/debug Feature Scenarios. My tool-set is RubyMine, Ruby, watir, page-object-gem, and Cucumber. I have a dual monitor setup, but the browser always comes up on the same monitor as Rubymine.

I made some changes to my hooks.rb file:

```
Before do
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
  @browser.window.move_to(1985,24)
  @browser.window.maximize 
  puts " Browser Position " + @browser.window.position.to_s
end

After do
  @browser.close
end
```

This is a very clunky solution. It always comes up on the same monitor as rubymine then moves. I had to hard-code position to use 2nd monitor, so it probably won't work on a different dual-monitor setup.

Question:

1. If there is a config item for this, what is it?
2. Can you suggest a way to implement the following and where would it go?

   If(dual_monitor) 
   then browser.move.window_to(other_monitor)

Comment: I don't see how, the browser placement will use whatever OS mechanism in place when it's launched. Maybe another intellij window used exclusively to start up the tests.

Comment: I do believe this is an OS controlled thing, I can easily manipulate which monitor the new browser opens on by just clicking inside that monitor with my mouse before it opens. However with my setup I just use the move_to method to move the browser where i want after it opens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I write tests at home and in the office and I have dual monitors in both places, and they are different sizes, I just use an environment variable:

```
if ENV['MOVE_BROWSER'] =~ /home/i
  browser.window.move_to(2080,0)
elsif ENV['MOVE_BROWSER'] =~ /office/i
  browser.window.move_to(-2562, -600)   
end

screen_width = browser.execute_script("return screen.width;")
screen_height = browser.execute_script("return screen.height;")
browser.driver.manage.window.resize_to(screen_width,screen_height)
```

This also ensures other testers are not affected by my preferences. I use Sublime on the largest available screen, and then have the browser on the other.

Comment: thanks, i will give it a try. where do you place this script, in your hooks.rb?

Comment: It would be ideal if Jetbrains added an option for this feature, it is very annoying to see how Chrome shows up hiding what you are doing.